# Запятые или тире?

Tags: запятые, тире, однородные-члены

Он подбежал к шкафу в коридоре, распахнул дверцу и стал быстро нажимать на кнопки, ни секунды не мешкая, чтобы не забыть очерёдность: зелёная — синяя — жёлтая — зелёная — синяя — оранжевая — красная.

Возможно ли такое обозначение чередования или порядка цветов? Или только через запятые?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое оформление чередования вполне допустимо. Более того, на письме выглядит даже лучше, чем запятые между словами однородного ряда.

Вот и правило нашлось ([**Однородные члены предложения, не соединенные союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=313#), Розенталь):

> 2. Для усиления выразительности и интонационного членения допускается постановка **тире** между однородными членами предложения: *Все говорят одно и то же: **Распутин — царица — немцы — война — революция*** (М. Г.); *Вспоминается цепь событий: **приезд Веры — знакомство — разговоры о литературе и искусстве — объяснение — отказ — расставание.***